# How do i give download option in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using the fancy box to display the images in my wordpress theme.
Following is the code i am using to display the images.

```
   <?php                    
                     if ( get_post_gallery() ):             
                        $gallery = get_post_gallery($post,false);
                        $ids= explode(',', $gallery['ids']);
                ?>            
                <?php 
                foreach( $ids AS $id ): 
                ?>
                <?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id,'thumbnail');
                      $src1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id,'full');

                ?>
                  <a class="fancybox-buttons col-sm-4 col-xs-6  paper_img" data-fancybox-group="button" href="<?php echo $src1[0];?>" title="">
                    <img src="<?php echo $src[0];?>" class=" fancybox-image img-responsive"/>
                  </a>                      
                <?php 
                endforeach;     
                endif;       
                ?>
```

This is the js i have been using which i got from somewhere

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
    $('.fancybox-buttons').attr("rel", "gallery").fancybox({     
        afterLoad: function () {
                this.title = this.title ?
                    '<a href="' + this.href.replace( "download")
                    .replace(".jpg", ".jpg") +
                    '">Download</a> ' + this.title 
                :
                    '<a href="' + this.href.replace( "download")
                    .replace(".jpg", ".jpg") +
                    '">Download</a>';
            },   

        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',

        prevEffect : 'none',
        nextEffect : 'none',

        closeBtn  : false,

        helpers : {
          title : {
            type : 'inside'
          },
          buttons : {}
        },        
      });
    });
```

The problem is that when i click on download button it takes me to the new window to the url of image instead of downloading it.

What i am doing wrong or can you provide me with some other alternative

Comment: You have the image as your href, so it will link to the image just as it should. you need 'download' as an attribute of the 'a' tag, not its innerhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 has a [download attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute) which you can use to force the download, however, older browsers will still just open the image in the browser window.

```
'<a href="' + this.href.replace( "download")
.replace(".jpg", ".jpg") +
'" download="filename.jpg">Download</a> ' + this.title
```

Here's a list of [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)

Comment: @APAD1 Man u r awesome , worked beautifully thanks a lot

Comment: No worries, if you want to change the name of the file that gets downloaded, just adjust the `="filename.jpg"` part, you can use variables if you want. Otherwise, if you just want it to download with the same filename it has on the server, you can remove the `="filename.jpg"` part altogether like in @Zeshan answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a download attribute to anchor tag as follow

```
<a href="imagelocation" download>
```

Change afterLoad as follow

```
    afterLoad: function () {
            this.title = this.title ?
                '<a href="' + this.href.replace( "download")
                .replace(".jpg", ".jpg") +
                '" download>Download</a> ' + this.title 
            :
                '<a href="' + this.href.replace( "download")
                .replace(".jpg", ".jpg") +
                '" download>Download</a>';
        },
```